# WPF Unbinding OnPropertyChanged-events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, gridview, telerik-grid

I have a wpf app, MVVM-style, with a (Telerik Rad)Gridview. I want to have an event every time user updates a cell.

The GridView is bound to the MyRowModel

```
public class MyRowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   //...
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
     {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
}
```

1. 

I want to handle them in my View Model, I bind them like this

```
var rows  = MyRows.ForEach(p=> p.PropertyChanged += MyPropertyChangedHandler);
```

This works, but do I need to unbind the events somewhere? The user can move back from this view, and select another set of rows. Moreover I will get updated rows from servier every time there is a cell change.

2, bonus question)
Are these (in my case MyRowModel ) View Models or Models?

Comment: Try `WeakEvent`. You can use WPF implementation or open source. Finally, you can implement yourself. It is not a magic.

Comment: Question 1. Detach those event when you remove/delete any row from `GridView`. Question 2. Those ViewModel are `Models` as they don't have any `View` associated with them.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. I'll check out where I can detach the events and check out Weak Events also. Ok, that makes sense to call them models, since they dont have a view

Comment: @Cowborg What type is `MyRows`? How do you bind `MyRows`, can you show the XAML? How is this done _The user can move back from this view, and select another set of rows._?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but do I need to unbind the events somewhere?

It depends on the lifetime of the involved objects. If you don't want the `MyRowModel` objects to prevent the view model from being garbage collection when you have navigated away from it, you should unregister the event handlers when the view is `Unloaded` and register them when it is `Loaded`:

```
 MyRows.ForEach(p=> p.PropertyChanged -= MyPropertyChangedHandler);
```

If items are dynamically added to and removed from `MyRows`, you should also detect when this happens and register and unregister the event handler accordingly. If `MyRows` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, you could [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564981/7252182) the `CollectionChanged` event.

If you consider using weak events, you should also consider the [semantic differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201093/is-it-safe-to-replace-all-standard-event-handler-to-weakeventmanager-or-its-vari/43204926#43204926) between using the `WeakEventManager` and the `+=` operator to hook up event handlers.

Comment: I "manually" unregister the events now, when user backs out of that view